# Postgres JSON Query on Unknown Keys

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column where the structure always remains the same, but the keys within the json may change.  For example,

```
{
   "key-12345": 
    {
       "values-12345": [
          {"type": 5200, 
           "source": "somesource", 
           "messageid": 707643203507, 
           "timestamp": "2018-07-26T21:25:42.612Z", 
           "destination": "somedestination", 
           "previouslyRouted": false
          }, 
          {"type": 5200, 
           "source": "anothersource", 
           "messageid": 707643203507, 
           "timestamp": "2018-07-26T21:26:01.542Z", 
           "destination": "anotherdestination", 
           "previouslyRouted": false
           }
         ]
       },

   "key-6789": 
    {
       "values-34512": [
          {"type": 5200, 
           "source": "yetantohersomesource", 
           "messageid": 707643203507, 
           "timestamp": "2018-07-26T21:25:42.612Z", 
           "destination": "yetanothersomedestination", 
           "previouslyRouted": false
          }, 
          {"type": 5200, 
           "source": "anothersource", 
           "messageid": 707643203507, 
           "timestamp": "2018-07-26T21:26:01.542Z", 
           "destination": "anotherdestination", 
           "previouslyRouted": false
           }
         ]
       }
}
```

I know that the structure of that document will be the same, but the keys could be anything.  I can pull the keys themselves out with

```
select jsonb_object_keys(column) from table;
```

easily enough but I don't know how to pull the object assigned to that key and deal with it.  How do I select from a jsonb object based on the value of a key, rather than the values.

```
select object from document where json_key = 'key-12345';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done:

```
SELECT object->>'key-12345' FROM document;
```

and with a where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE object->>'key-12345' IS NOT NULL;
```